# Call Sitecore SPEAK from OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sitecore

I have a custom speak js method and would like to call it from Telerik grid by clicking on one of the buttons. Is it possible to use OneClientClick to call my method? I tried:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" OnClientClick = "javascript:myMethod()" runat="server" CommandName="MyMethod">Call my method</asp:LinkButton>`

but nothing happens.`MyMethod` doesn't really do anything, I'd like js method to execute.

Comment: James, If that JS file/function is not loaded then it won't be called. Just make sure that in browser's Inspect window, you can see that function loaded or check if can you call js function from the console? If not then try to debug in console.